# Access97: INSERT INTO if not exists

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-97

I need to do a very simple task: execute an INSERT INTO query only if the record doesn't exist in the table.
I found a lot of hints out there but none of them work in SQL Access97.

Example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Smith' )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('John', 'Smith')
END
```

this won't work because IF NOT EXISTS is not valid.

What is the right way to do this in one SQL clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build that into an `insert . ..  select`:

```
INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName)
    SELECT TOP 1 'John', 'Smith'
    FROM Users
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Smith' );
```